# How can I parse success or throw error with HttpBuilder-ng

Tags: rest, groovy, marshalling, spock, httpbuilder-ng

I'm building a groovy rest client for my java app to use with test automation. I originally wrote the service in httpBuilder, but couldn't figure out how to parse the response. On non-200 responses, I got an exception which I could catch and assert on the message. Not found, bad request, etc. After updating, I can parse the response, but anytime I get a non-200 response, it tries to parse it as my object which then throws a useless 'missingProperty' exception. The doc shows how to parse the response using `response.parser <CONTENT_TYPE>, { config, fs ->...}`, and how to branch on the status code using `response.success{fs -> ...}`, or `response.when(<CODE>){fs -> ...}`, but not how to parse only for success and use different logic for failure. My current code is as follows:

```
import groovyx.net.http.ChainedHttpConfig
import groovyx.net.http.FromServer
import groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.NativeHandlers

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentTypes.JSON
import static groovyx.net.http.NativeHandlers.Parsers.json

class CarClient {

    private final HttpBuilder http

    CarClient() {
        http = HttpBuilder.configure {
            request.uri = "localhost:8080"
            request.encoder JSON, NativeHandlers.Encoders.&json
        }
    }

    List<Car> getCars(make) {
        http.get(List) {
            request.uri.path = "/cars/make/${make}"
            response.failure { fs ->
                println("request failed: ${fs}")
            }
            response.parser JSON, { ChainedHttpConfig config, FromServer fs ->
                json(config, fs).collect { x -> new Car(make: x."make", model: x."model") }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Car {
    def make
    def model
}
```

then my spock tests:

```
def "200 response should return list of cars"() {
  when:
  def result = client.getCars("honda")
  then:
  result.size == 3
  result[0].make == "honda"
  result[0].model == "accord"
}

def "404 responses should throw exception with 'not found'"() {
  when:
  client.getCars("ford")
  then:
  final Exception ex = thrown()
  ex.message == "Not Found"
}
```

Under the old version the first test failed, and the second test passed. Under new version, the first test passes and the second test fails. I never actually see the `request failed:...` message, either. i just get a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`. when I step through, I can see it trying to load the `not found` response as a Car object.

Bonus: why do i have to use explicit property mappings instead of groovy casting like in the doc?

```
json(config, fs).collect { x -> x as Car }
```

update - For clarification, this isn't my actual source. I'm hitting a proprietary internal API running on WAS, which I don't fully control. I am writing the API's business logic, but response is being marshalled/unmarshalled using WAS and proprietary libraries to which I do not have access. Names have been changed to protect the innocent/my job. These are the workarounds I've tried since initial post:
This triggers the failure block correctly on non-200 responses, but the parsing fails with `IO - stream closed` error. Also, any exceptions i throw in the failure block get wrapped in a RuntimeException which prevents me from accessing the info. I've tried wrapping it in a transport exception as suggested in the doc, but it's still a RuntimeException by the time i get it.

```
    List<Car> getCars(make) {
        http.get(List) {
            request.uri.path = "/cars/make/${make}"
            response.failure { fs ->
              println("request failed: ${fs}")
              throw new AutomationException("$fs.statusCode : $fs.message")
            }
            response.success { FromServer fs ->
               new JsonSlurper().parse(new InputStreamReader(fs.getInputStream, fs.getCharset())).collect { x -> new Car(make: x."make", model: x."model") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This one parses correctly on 200 responses with entries, 200's with no entries still throw missing property exceptions. Like the previous impl, the AutomationException is wrapped and therefor not useful.

```
    List<Car> getCars(make) {
        http.get(List) {
            request.uri.path = "/cars/make/${make}"
            response.parser JSON, { ChainedHttpConfig config, FromServer fs ->
            if (fs.statusCode == 200) { 
                json(config, fs).collect { x -> new Car(make: x."make", model: x."model") }
            } else {
              throw new AutomationException("$fs.statusCode : $fs.message")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the bonus, the guide I was following showed implicit casting of the `json(config, fs)` output to the Car object. I have to explicitly set the props of the new object. Not a big deal, but it makes me wonder if I've configured something else incorrectly.

Comment: I also find this frustrating!
if you declare a parser in your configuration, and if for some reason the parser fails, you will have a null object returns.
Seems there is no way to handle the Parser error.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an Exception in the `failure` handler and it will do what you are looking for:

```
response.failure { fs ->
    throw new IllegalStateException('No car found')
}
```

I am not sure what server you are testing against, so I wrote a test using [Ersatz](http://stehno.com/ersatz):

```
import com.stehno.ersatz.ErsatzServer
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Specification

import static com.stehno.ersatz.ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON

class CarClientSpec extends Specification {

    @AutoCleanup('stop')
    private final ErsatzServer server = new ErsatzServer()

    def 'successful get'() {
        setup:
        server.expectations {
            get('/cars/make/Toyota').responder {
                content '[{"make":"Toyota","model":"Corolla"}]', APPLICATION_JSON
            }
        }

        CarClient client = new CarClient(server.httpUrl)

        when:
        List<Car> cars = client.getCars('Toyota')

        then:
        cars.size() == 1
        cars.contains(new Car('Toyota', 'Corolla'))
    }

    def 'failed get'() {
        setup:
        server.expectations {
            get('/cars/make/Ford').responds().code(404)
        }

        CarClient client = new CarClient(server.httpUrl)

        when:
        client.getCars('Ford')

        then:
        def ex = thrown(IllegalStateException)
        ex.message == 'No car found'
    }
}
```

Note that I had to make your client have a configurable base url (and `Car` needed the `@Canonical` annotation). If you haven't read the blog post about [Take a REST with HttpBuilder-NG and Ersatz](http://coffeaelectronica.com/blog/2017/rest-httpbuilder-ersatz.html) I would suggest doing so as it provides a good overview.

I am not sure what you mean in your bonus question.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think the issue is that the response is always coming back with a content type `application/json`, so the parser always gets triggered. I've tried removing the parser and calling the 'new JSONSlurper(...fs.getIntputStream) in the success closure, but that throws a `stream closed` error. Best I've got so far is adding try catch in the parser closure before invoking the native handler, but the exception handling is muddled, and it still chokes on a 200 returning an empty list. Trying to build test w/ ersatz, but it's a side project, so not much time to work on it.